# Should I always write this.props when passing props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am fetching `props` from redux store object `user`.

And when I pass it to my component children, I implement it like follows

```
render(){
 return(
  <Component 
     num={this.props.user.num}
     id={this.props.user.id}
     name={this.props.user.name}/>
 )
}
```

or should I extract my variables much earlier?

```
render(){
 const {num, id, name} = this.props.user;
 return(
  <Component 
     num={num}
     id={id}
     name={name}/>
 )
}
```

Which has better performance ?

NOTE: `this.props.user` is a large JSON , So I do not want to use like this

`<Component {...this.props.user}/>`

Comment: `<Component {...{id, num, name}} />`

Comment: Not sure about the performance. I don't think there is a big difference. Personally I'd writed this: const { user: { num, id, name } } = this.props;

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I am aware of that, but that would mean I would have to extract much earlier `const {num, id, name} = this.props.user;`

Comment: @Rodius Really wanna check performance difference

Comment: Yes, you do. But it is a bit shorter than specifying names twice. Anyway I'm voting to close the question as it is pretty much opinion based.

Comment: `Should I always write this.props when passing props?` The answer would be no, it depends. But in your example I don't see the big benefits of doing `const {num, id, name} = this.props.user;`. And if you did I can't see how it would hurt performance. It's value extraction from an object literal. `let name = this.props.user.name` wouldn't cost much in performance (I think).

Comment: i am always in favor of `destructuring`. more readable and if you want to change the object "origin" you do it once. for example, if now you want to refactor the code and wants the "props" to be stored in the local state you just need to change one thing:  `const {...} = this.props;` -> `const {...} = this.state;`

Comment: I'm also in favor of destructuring since it is more readable. However I don't think that the way you pass props to inner components can impact so heavily performances since props can be thought as parameters of a function that are passed by reference.

Comment: You would use {...this.props.user} when  you wanna pass all the props down to the component, otherwise prefer destructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two questions.

> The question in the title: "Should I always write this.props when passing props?"

There's no way to access the properties unless you write `this.props.whatever`. So in the beginning you need it. Then, if you wish to refactor it, so you don't have to type `this.props.~` every time, you extract each desired property into a variable.

> The question at the end of the question body: "Which has better performance ?"

I think they would perform just about the same, but in terms of space efficiency, you would be creating extra variables with the destructuring. But I don't think that would be very significant in your case. So, for the sake of readability and cleaner code, why not destructure?